# Stop Deluge downloading when VPN drops

Tags: vpn, deluge

Since I'm completely a noob in scripting, is there an efficient way to check every second the existence of the tun0 interface (corresponding to my vpn) and if it is down then deluge would stop downloading?

Next step would be to resume if tun0 is up again but let's troubleshoot the first case first. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, seems I was a bit too fast. I found a partial solution to the problem. Create a file `check_tun0.sh` and store it in `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d`. The script is run with `root:root` permissions.

The script:

```
#!/bin/sh
# use tail - /var/log/syslog in terminal to check if it is executed the four lines help you spot easily

logger -s XXXXXXXXXX
logger -s $1
logger -s $2
logger -s XXXXXXXXXX


if [ $2 = "vpn-down" ]
    then
# Stop downloads if vpn is down
    deluge-console "pause *; quit"
fi
```

Why aren't the commands executed, whereas they run fine in the terminal? I replaced the `deluge-console` commands with a `killall deluged` as an example and the script works. So obviously I can't run `deluge-console` commands in the script. Why is that? Also, do you have an idea to extend this to support resume of downloas as soon as `tun0` is re-enabled?